# How can I display User Email or Id in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to display user email and Id. I wrote a code, it was working, then for no reason it display null now. How can I fix this?

[image: screen]

```
import 'package:file_picker/file_picker.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
import 'package:flutter_dev/reusable.dart';

class Fy extends StatefulWidget {
  const Fy({super.key});

  @override
  State<Fy> createState() => _FyState();
}

class _FyState extends State<Fy> {
  PlatformFile? pickedFile;


  dynamic UserId;
  dynamic UserMail;

  Future Please() async{
    FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges().listen((User? user) {
      if (user != null) {
        setState(() {
          UserId = user.uid;
          UserMail = user.email;
        });
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: [
          Text(
            'Hello $UserMail',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
          Text(
            '$UserId',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's not working because no authState changes are taking place. Your user is logged in, and unless you log him out, he won't undergo any auth state changes. A simple and not as elegant solution could be to simply call the user, and then display the attributes in the UI. Something like this:

```
class Fy extends StatefulWidget {
  const Fy({super.key});

  @override
  State<Fy> createState() => _FyState();
}

class _FyState extends State<Fy> {
  PlatformFile? pickedFile;

  user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: [
          Text(
            'Hello ${user.email}',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
          Text(
            '${user.uid}',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Gotchu bro @Boatti